# Is Hyperledger wallet same as Metamask?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Hyperledger has this wallet thing where a set of user identities are stored.  I am trying to understand if this concept of wallet in Hyperledger is the same as the one used in Metamask.  For example, when you want to use a dApp, you need to have Metamask extension installed in a chrome browser.  Then the dApp use your Metamask address to identify you.  How does that relate to Hyperledger wallet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case Hyperledger Fabric, the user/client application have to do two steps to commit a transaction to the blockchain ledger.

1. Get transaction endorsements from enough number of peers
2. Send the endorsed transaction to orderer to get the transaction included in a block.

The user has to sign these transaction endorsement and ordering proposal before sending to peers/orderer. The wallet stores the private key and certificate of the user for this signing purpose. This way, client authenticates the requests to peers/orderers. Usually, wallet is managed using the application SDKs. Refer HLF Node SDK [wallet documentation](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-2.2/tutorial-wallet.html) for more details.

[HLF official documentation of wallet](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/developapps/wallet.html).

Comment: So the use of wallet in Hyperledger is really different from that in Metamask, am I correct?

Comment: @iPhoneJavaDev there are differences in implementation. Private keys are encrypted in Metamask, Metamask is not storing a certificate like the fabric wallet etc. But the basic purpose of Metamask is also to sign transactions using the stored private key. Another point is regarding where the wallet is located. In case of Fabric, the wallet will mostly reside in the server holding credentials of users. But metamask is used at the client side and holds credentials of a single user only.